# Continuous radial functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider a function $u \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n), n \geq 2$, where $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ denotes the usual Sobolev space. Ordinarily this does not have to be continuous, but would it be continuous if we added the additional criterion that $u$ is a radial function? Thanks for your help.

Edit after Ian's comment: Is it possible to conclude that the function is continuous outside a compact set?

Comment: No, actually they needn't even be $L^\infty$. $\log(\log(1+1/r))$ is a nice example in 2 dimensions.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for your input. I have edited the question.

Comment: I assume now there is some "up to modification on a set of measure zero" issues. ($1_{\mathbb{Q}^n}$ rears its head at this question...)